# Different count of Buffers: shared hit when run the same query second time

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, psql

PostgreSQL 13.7 (Debian 13.7-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit

auto_explain.log_analyze: true

auto_explain.log_buffers: true

The postgresql log show me a long running query with execution plan:

```
2023-11-03 08:24:51.481 MSK [1094142] User: otrs; Session: 65447e70.10b1fe; DB: otrs; Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(41236) LOG:  duration: 8176.464 ms  plan:
        Query Text: SELECT DISTINCT st.id, st.tn, st.create_time FROM ticket st INNER JOIN dynamic_field_value dfv1
                                ON (st.id = dfv1.object_id
                                    AND dfv1.field_id = 200)  WHERE 1=1 AND ( LOWER(dfv1.value_text) = LOWER('CCS-4180967 [9954762722309]') ) ORDER BY st.create_time DESC LIMIT 1
        Limit  (cost=1001.23..2173.05 rows=1 width=30) (actual time=8121.116..8176.458 rows=0 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=13853718
          ->  Unique  (cost=1001.23..2397368.81 rows=2045 width=30) (actual time=8121.114..8176.455 rows=0 loops=1)
                Buffers: shared hit=13853718
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1001.23..2397353.47 rows=2045 width=30) (actual time=8121.113..8176.454 rows=0 loops=1)
                      Buffers: shared hit=13853718
                      ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.80..621301.27 rows=3339010 width=30) (actual time=64.816..1305.832 rows=3728611 loops=1)
                            Workers Planned: 5
                            Workers Launched: 5
                            Buffers: shared hit=2209941
                            ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=0.72..218201.54 rows=667802 width=30) (actual time=4.200..1302.012 rows=621435 loops=6)
                                  Sort Key: st.create_time DESC, st.id, st.tn
                                  Presorted Key: st.create_time
                                  Full-sort Groups: 4947  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB
                                  Buffers: shared hit=2209941
                                  Worker 0:  Full-sort Groups: 22336  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB
                                  Worker 1:  Full-sort Groups: 22341  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB
                                  Worker 2:  Full-sort Groups: 22273  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB
                                  Worker 3:  Full-sort Groups: 22254  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB
                                  Worker 4:  Full-sort Groups: 22256  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB
                                  ->  Parallel Index Scan using ticket_create_time_desc_idx on ticket st  (cost=0.43..188150.45 rows=667802 width=30) (actual time=0.244..1076.668 rows=621435 loops=6)
                                        Buffers: shared hit=2209436
                      ->  Index Scan using dynamic_field_value_field_values on dynamic_field_value dfv1  (cost=0.43..0.52 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=3728611)
                            Index Cond: ((object_id = st.id) AND (field_id = 200))
                            Filter: (lower((value_text)::text) = 'ccs-4180967 [9954762722309]'::text)
                            Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                            Buffers: shared hit=11643777
```

After a few minutes I run EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for this query and get the same execution plan, but with another count of Buffers: shared hit and running much faster:

```
        Limit  (cost=1001.23..2173.08 rows=1 width=30) (actual time=13.219..25.331 rows=1 loops=1)"
          Buffers: shared hit=14869"
          ->  Unique  (cost=1001.23..2397423.81 rows=2045 width=30) (actual time=13.218..25.329 rows=1 loops=1)"
                Buffers: shared hit=14869"
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1001.23..2397408.47 rows=2045 width=30) (actual time=13.216..25.327 rows=1 loops=1)"
                      Buffers: shared hit=14869"
                      ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.80..621311.17 rows=3339010 width=30) (actual time=10.033..24.206 rows=250 loops=1)"
                            Workers Planned: 5"
                            Workers Launched: 5"
                            Buffers: shared hit=13977"
                            ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=0.72..218211.44 rows=667802 width=30) (actual time=2.592..8.813 rows=68 loops=6)"
                                  Sort Key: st.create_time DESC, st.id, st.tn"
                                  Presorted Key: st.create_time"
                                  Full-sort Groups: 2  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB"
                                  Buffers: shared hit=13977"
                                  Worker 0:  Full-sort Groups: 3  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB"
                                  Worker 1:  Full-sort Groups: 3  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB"
                                  Worker 2:  Full-sort Groups: 4  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB"
                                  Worker 3:  Full-sort Groups: 2  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB"
                                  Worker 4:  Full-sort Groups: 4  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB"
                                  ->  Parallel Index Scan using ticket_create_time_desc_idx on ticket st  (cost=0.43..188160.35 rows=667802 width=30) (actual time=0.196..8.521 rows=97 loops=6)"
                                        Buffers: shared hit=13472"
                      ->  Index Scan using dynamic_field_value_field_values on dynamic_field_value dfv1  (cost=0.43..0.52 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=250)"
                            Index Cond: ((object_id = st.id) AND (field_id = 200))"
                            Filter: (lower((value_text)::text) = 'ccs-4180967 [9954762722309]'::text)"
                            Rows Removed by Filter: 1"
                            Buffers: shared hit=892"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=18"
"Planning Time: 0.642 ms"
"Execution Time: 25.391 ms"
```

'Ticket' and 'dynamic_field_value' tables are freshly analyzed.

Why do the Buffers:shared hit count vary so much?

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer overlooked the real glaring difference here.  The first execution had to go through 3728611 tickets before finding one which pairs up with a dynamic_field_value it could keep (actually, it never even found one), while the second execution only had to go through 250 before finding a keeper.  So the first one had to hit more buffers just because it had to do more work.  (I scrolled up and down to see where the buffer counts diverged, but not left and right to see that the actual row count also diverged)

Presumably what happens is the first query somehow leads downstream to a new ticket being generated, and now when you repeat the query with this slightly altered data that new ticket is among the first ones to be tested and it gets to stop early.  Or, it leads to some dynamic_field_value being altered so it now meets the 'lower' condition when before it didn't.  When you have a `LIMIT 1`, just a small change in data can lead to a huge change in performance.  And of course just a couple minutes is plenty of time for a small change in data to happen, especially if the change happens by design and not randomly.